# Escaped characters not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Click me1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Click me2</button>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Python\x20Auto\x20\x26lt\x3Bscript\x20type\x26\x23x3d\x3B\x26quot\x3Btext\x26\x23x2f\x3Bjavascript\x26quot\x3B\x26gt\x3B\x20alert\x26\x23x28\x3B\x26quot\x3BJavaScript\x20alert\x26quot\x3B\x26\x23x29\x3B\x26\x23x3b\x3B\x20\x26lt\x3B\x26\x23x2f\x3Bscript\x26gt\x3B\x20";
}
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "'Python&#x5c;x20Auto&#x5c;x20&#x5c;x3Cscript&#x5c;x20type&#x5c;x3D&#x5c;x22text&#x5c;x2Fjavascript&#x5c;x22&#x5c;x3E&#x5c;x20alert&#x5c;x28&#x5c;x22JavaScript&#x5c;x20alert&#x5c;x22&#x5c;x29&#x5c;x3B&#x5c;x20&#x5c;x3C&#x5c;x2Fscript&#x5c;x3E&#x5c;x20'";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two "p" elements named demo1 and demo2. The demo1 element is programmed to set to a text that's escaped by **html first** and after that escaped by **javascript**. the demo 2 element is programmed to set its innerHtml to a text that has been escaped by **javascript first** and **html next**.
I have placed two buttons. **Click me 1** and **Click me 2**. When you click those two, You will see demo1 element shows the text correctly unescaped but demo2 element is not showing its text correctly. Can some one explain this scenario ?

Comment: It shows exactly what you requested it `&#x5c;x20` is a `\ ` character followed by `x20`

Comment: @zerkms so ultimately it reflects the demo1 innerHtml right. Why doesn't it executed like the "Click me 1"

Comment: Which functions did you use for escaping?

Comment: @Lloyd95 "so ultimately it reflects the demo1 innerHtml right" --- no, not right. It produces the slash character followed by `x20`. Literally. You cannot encode something multiple times and expect it will be decoded multiple times.

Comment: @Novice org.owasp.esapi.Encoder class, encodeForJavaScript and encodeForHtml methods.